# creating liquidEffect in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

friends I am new in game development programing .And I want to understand the how to give liquidEffect to text & and to the image in window base application.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific - are you trying to use a game engine? If so, which one? If not, what should the "liquid effect" look like?

Comment: I just want to understand how to create  liquidEffect in iphone.I see this liquidEffect in game but i want liquideffect in my window base application .how can i do that.

Comment: Pour water on the screen. (Note: don't actually do this.)

Comment: (In other words, we don't know what you're actually asking for. "liquidEffect" is not a programming term.)

Comment: I actually want to give liquideffect to text & image in my  application

Comment: You actually said that before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. At least there's no easy way to do so. It would at least involve taking screenshots of the content you'd like to liquify. Then you would need to map the image to a grid which you would warp, or apply some kind of filter to the image.

Either way you would have to do it from scratch. The only hint I can give you is [look at cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/). It is a game engine, but it features the ripple effect and maybe you could use it for at least the part of your application that requires the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use Open GL ES.

Convert your image to a texture map.  Tile the image rectangle with small triangles.  Animate or jiggle the tile coordinates over time, and use Open GL to render the warped textures in animation frame callbacks.

Comment: can you send me the sample code.To better understand the concept

Comment: There's sample code in some of the Open GL books.  None that I can post.